# How can I tell lstlisting to use sans-serif when escaping to math mode?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, listings, sans-serif

Title says it all, an example follows:

```
\lstset{
    mathescape=true,
    basicstyle = \sffamily
}

\begin{lstlisting}
    func($x_0$)
\end{lstlisting}
```

Where and how can I set the math font used here to be sans-serif italic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\DeclareMathVersion{sans}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}  {sans}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}  {sans}{OMS}{cmbrs}{m}{n}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{sflisting}[1][]
  {\lstset{#1}\mathversion{sans}}{}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
    mathescape=true,
    basicstyle = \sffamily
}

\begin{sflisting}[caption=Function]
    func($x_0$)
\end{sflisting}
\end{document}
```

This uses the CMBright fonts, which are mostly compatible with CM Sans.

Comment: Looks like the right approach, but using it the caption and label doesn't work anymore, see [here](http://pastie.org/2098837). "Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 26."

Comment: @neo: define the environment like this: `\lstnewenvironment{sflisting}[2]
  {\mathversion{sans},\lstset{caption=\lstname#1,label=#2}}{}` and use it like: `\begin{sflisting}{<caption>}{<label>}...\end{sflisting}`.

Comment: @neo: see edited answer

Comment: Thanks, captions etc. now work, but the actual math font in the listing is quite pixelated when zoomed in. The version from Herbert's answer looks smooth. Why is that?

Comment: You probably don't have the Type1 version of the CMBright fonts, which however is in TeX Live and I believe also in MiKTeX (hfbright should be the name of the package to install). It depends on your system. What answer to choose depends mostly on the math contents of your listings.

Comment: I use MiKTeX and have installed hfbright now and it looks perfect now, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{sflisting}[1][]
  {\lstset{mathescape,basicstyle=\sffamily,#1}\sansmath}
  {}
\begin{document}

\begin{sflisting}[caption=Function]
    func($\frac1x \mathrm{d}x$)
\end{sflisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works quite good, although sansmath doesn't use sans greek letters which I need. The documentation says to use [eulergreek] to get those in sans, but then unfortunately greek letters are always non-italic, maybe a bug?

Comment: @neo: with option `[eulergreek]` they are upright, compare the `\beta` symbol with and without the option.